# How do I include a module in my Erlang project?

Tags: module, erlang

I want to use this in my Erlang project: https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx

My file tree looks like this:
`server/` -> compiled files
`includes/jsx/` -> module I want to use

Erlang (in the server folder) does not find the jsx module so my guess is that I have to import it, how do I do that?

Comment: start your erlang session with `erl -pa includes/jsx/` or replace `includes/jsx/` with the absolute path to the source/binary files

Comment: @bjhaid your answer is correct, so why not put it in the answer field and maybe expand a little? ;-)